# How I can get the exifinterface Datetime

Tags: java, android

My path /storage/emulated/0/saved_images/IMG_20220417_105506.jpg

I use the exifinterface to get the date of image but when I call it will return null . Why?

```
exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);

String EXIFdateString = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);
```

Comment: Can you read other tags? Android version of used device?

Comment: not every jpg has to have exif data! if TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL is null, that means there is no attribute for datetime stored in the metadata of your jpg